# Intellisense for Visual Studio Code - too many suggestions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a C# developer normally, so maybe this is something I don't understand about Python.

I have a data model of dataclasses with < 10 child data elements in each class.

e.g. things like:

```
@dataclass
class Block:
    def tranmission(this) -> Transmission:
       ...

    def allocations(this) -> Generator[Allocation,Any,Any]:
       ...

    def day(this) -> Day:
       ...
```

so when I add a "." and look in intellisense, I'm expecting a nice short list of options, but I seem to be something more like 100.

Intellisense DOES include my methods, but they are drowning in sea of other stuff I'm not interested in and not sure why are there,

[image]

block.return and block.True seem to make no sense to me at all.

Why is it doing it? and how do I just see a more focused and useful list.

Ideally all the seemingly useless suggestions could be filtered out, if not, if i can prioritise my methods to the top of the list would help.

---

The only idea i have at the moment (which is awful) is to have a naming convention prefix for my methods, then I can find them by typing the prefix into intellisense! surely there must be a better way that this?

---

This only seems to effect the 'if' clause, and actually it only seems to effect me, so I'm going to live with it, and factor our if clauses into functions if it causes me a problem (its a similar issue to lambdas, that don't support type annotations)

Comment: Is your code (partially) typed? If the Python server (Jedi or Pylance) cannot deduce the type of `block`, then it cannot provide auto-completion for it. Depending on the version of VS Code you're using, you can also try switching from Jedi to Pylance language server by setting `python.languageServer` to `Pylance` (this is the default for the latest releases but has been available for some time).

Comment: C# is statically type which makes it far easier to know the scope of names.

Comment: so yes, it is partially typed, the data model is big and complex so typing it and letting intellisense take part of the strain works brilliantly in C#. Intellisense DOES include the correct values, just about 100 other things too.

Comment: my extension says [Info  - 8:57:09 AM] Pylance language server 2021.10.0 (pyright d5878534) starting...so I think I'm on pylance already

Comment: @Holt - so I think the typechecker can deduce the types, its just including all sort of other stuff I'm not interested in.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output... I get a few more elements because Python has a lots hidden fields/methods but nothing like your screenshot. It's possibly a bug in Pylance that occurs in specific situation. You can try reporting on their Github.

Comment: @Holt - try doing it inside a list comprehension, it seems to work sensibly outside that

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd That's what I did, with your class and some dummy ones for `Transmission`, `Allocation`, etc.

Comment: @Holt - I think I'm going to live with it for the moment, I can factor out the 'if' clause into a function and intellisense works sensibly - thanks very much for your help